# Yup conditional using `when` with radio inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup, react-hook-form

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (probably something silly). I'm using React Hook Form with Yup and trying to have a condition based on how one checks the radio group.

Basically, if you check the *first* radio, then only **one** field is required.
However, if you check the *second* radio, then **both** text fields are required.

I think I'm messing up the `validationSchema` somehow but I'm failing to see it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    decide: yup.string(),
    one: yup.string().required(),
    two: yup.string().when("decide", {
      is: "decideBoth",
      then: yup.string().required(),
      otherwise: yup.string().notRequired()
    })
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({ validationSchema });

  function handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setDecide(value);
  }

  const [decide, setDecide] = useState("decideOne");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(console.log)}>
        <div>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="decide"
            id="decideOne"
            value="decideOne"
            checked={decide === "decideOne"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="decideOne">only one required</label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="decide"
            id="decideBoth"
            value="decideBoth"
            checked={decide === "decideBoth"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="decideBoth">both required</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="one">one</label>
          <input ref={register} type="text" name="one" />
          {errors.one && <p>{errors.one.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="two">two</label>
          <input ref={register} type="text" name="two" />
          {errors.two && <p>{errors.two.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a link to the https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-beaver-dce80?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: you could put conditional over your validation schema as well.
If decideOne then one schema 
If decideBoth then another schema.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but shouldn't it work either way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `register` to `ref` callback of radio buttons.
Here is the working code. Also, I've removed `useState` for `decide` as it is going to be handled by `react-hook-form`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    decide: yup.string(),
    one: yup.string().required(),
    two: yup.string().when("decide", (val, schema) => {
      console.log("when", val);
      if (val === "decideBoth") return yup.string().required();
      else return yup.string().notRequired();
    })
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, getValues } = useForm({
    validationSchema,
    defaultValues: {
      decide: "decideOne"
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("On Submit", data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <input
            ref={register}
            type="radio"
            name="decide"
            id="decideOne"
            value="decideOne"
            defaultChecked={getValues("decide") === "decideOne"}
            // onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="decideOne">only one required</label>
          <input
            ref={register}
            type="radio"
            name="decide"
            id="decideBoth"
            value="decideBoth"
            defaultChecked={getValues("decide") === "decideBoth"}
            // onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="decideBoth">both required</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="one">one</label>
          <input ref={register} type="text" name="one" />
          {errors.one && <p>{errors.one.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="two">two</label>
          <input ref={register} type="text" name="two" />
          {errors.two && <p>{errors.two.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-jackson-l14hj?file=/src/App.tsx